# How to pass an event from one element to another in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a text element in front of a rect element.
The rect element responds to `wheel` events so that it can be scrolled.
The text element responds to `drag` events so that it can be moved.

When the mouse pointer is over the text element, it blocks the rect element from getting the `wheel` event.

I cannot set `pointer-events` to `none` on the text element since it also needs to respond to click and drag.

When the `wheel` event is detected on the text element, is there a way to pass it on to the rect element?

I looked into the dispatch function, but I don't want to create a new event. I just want to pass along the event.

Calling the rect element's event handler when the text element gets the `wheel` event seems to work. This requires calling methods of unrelated objects, so I want to avoid it.

Here is some simplified code:

```js
var container = d3.create("svg:g")

var rectElem = container.append("rect")
 .on("wheel",handleScroll)

var textElem = container.append("text")
 .call(d3.drag().on("drag",handleDrag))
 .on("wheel",(e)=>{ 
   // How to send event to rect element ?
 })
```

Comment: Maybe something like [*"Capturing mouseover events on two overlapping elements"*](/q/58579309)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out from [altocumulus' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695676/how-to-pass-an-event-from-one-element-to-another-in-d3?noredirect=1#comment121403351_68695676) which points to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579309/capturing-mouseover-events-on-two-overlapping-elements) answer.

There are two ways to do this.

**Option 1**

The `wheel` event handling can be moved to the container element so that it bubbles up from both the rect element and the text element that are inside it.

```js
var container = d3.create("svg:g")
 .on("wheel",handleScroll)

var rectElem = container.append("rect")

var textElem = container.append("text")
 .call(d3.drag().on("drag",handleDrag))
```

**Option 2**

The event received by the text element can be cloned and dispatched to the rect element. (It has to be cloned. The same event can't be reused).

```js
var container = d3.create("svg:g")

var rectElem = container.append("rect")
.on("wheel",handleScroll)

var textElem = container.append("text")
 .call(d3.drag().on("drag",handleDrag))
 .on("wheel",(e)=>{rectElem.node().dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent(e.type,e))})
```